# adding an SSL cert to my Amazon AMI Linux distro

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I was following this how-to: https://nouveauframework.org/blog/installing-letsencrypts-free-ssl-amazon-linux/

and it leverages LetsEncrypt so i was happy to use it. I was entering this command and was getting error on the script.

Command:

> certbot-auto --debut -v --server
>   https://acme-v01.api.letsencrypt.org/directory certonly -d
>   mywebsite.com

It says it is creating the virtual environment but then fails.

```
/usr/local/bin/certbot-auto: line 679: virtualenv: command not found
```

I am not sure what that means. Maybe I am doing something wrong, but i dont really know what.

According to uname -a I am:

> Linux www.mywebsite.com 2.6.35.14-95.38.amzn1.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Aug 25
>   17:11:23 UTC 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Right now when i run the certbot-auto script, it checks that all the packages are the correct version so nothing else is installed.

Is there something wrong with Amazon AMI EC2 instance servers that prevent this?

Comment: `sudo certbot-auto ...`?

Comment: I tried that too.  I actually was working as root at the time for configuration purposes..

Comment: The error message is fairly clear that something it needs isn't available. [This github question](https://github.com/certbot/certbot/issues/2889) gives suggestions how to solve it, as does [this one](https://github.com/certbot/certbot/issues/2870).